# Dealing with missing exponent error javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a variable id (which i get from) my EJS file and I want to store it in java script variable.

**Here is the line**

```
 var getId= <%=chattingTo._id%>;
```

On browser the following line shows me, Syntax error missing exponent.

**The Variable in debug window**

```
var getId= 5eb3ad8deeaa65dc55c47a0f;
```

**I want to store this id(5eb3adddeeaa651c55c47a0f) into variable getId**

I have tried toString() method but it doesn't work, getting same missing exponent error.

**My Attempt**

```
var getId= toString(<%=chattingTo._id%>);
```

Comment: use:- var getId= "<%=chattingTo._id%>";